# FQL OFFSET limitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get all user ids from the people that likes a page's post. In the particular example the likes are ~22k.
However I can only get the first 1000.

With the following I get data:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM   like
WHERE  object_id = [ID]
LIMIT  1000
OFFSET 1
```

But not with this one:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM   like
WHERE  object_id = [ID]
LIMIT  1000
OFFSET 1001
```

So I guess the limitation of total id per post is 1000 and the only option is through Graph Api to get all the ids?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

**select like_info from stream where post_id='ID'**

where ID is id of Post